# How to remove overly large file from git push

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a file too large to `git push`, and I blindly did a lot operations which later proved to be in vain. Therefore, it is hard to keep track on what I have done to solve this problem.

I have tried something based on other posts, but after hitting bumps continuously, I deleted the large file from local directory and stored it somehwhere else. But when it comes to doing `git push`, it still reports,

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (12/12), completed with 7 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: c97c02f1e5c63de116140671bb54f0be
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File base_2019-07-29-19-04-00/val_loss_checkpoint.hdf5 is 202.28 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I thought `git` recorded something even though the file is not in the local repo any more. So I tried to remove the file by doing,

```
$ git rm --cached base_2019-07-29-19-04-00/val_loss_checkpoint.hdf5
fatal: pathspec 'base_2019-07-29-19-04-00/val_loss_checkpoint.hdf5' did not match any files
```

I am rather confused to understand what is going on and waiting for some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `git status`, I'm guessing you see something like this:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   base_2019-07-29-19-04-00/val_loss_checkpoint.hdf5
```

I think the command in parentheses on the third line is what you're looking for:

```
git reset HEAD base_2019-07-29-19-04-00/val_loss_checkpoint.hdf5
```

Note the `git rm` both deletes the file AND updates the git staging area. Since you've already deleted the file manually, use `git reset` to interact with the staging area alone.

Comment: @chirs thanks, though it doen't directly help solve my problem, but `git status` itself leads me to the solution.

Comment: @yujuezhao You may provide your solution by answering to your own question, in order to help future users who face the same problem